# FactoryGirl doesn't write data

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, factory-bot

I am so confused as to why this is happening...

I'm using factory girl, and this factory:

```
# spec/factories/partners/contact.rb

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :partner_contact, class: Partners::Contact do
    first_name "Josh"
    last_name { Faker::Name.last_name }
    email { Faker::Internet.email }
    partner
  end
end
```

But when I run my rspec it says

```
Mysql2::Error: Field 'first_name' doesn't have a default value: INSERT INTO `partner_contact` (`created_on`) VALUES ('2014-01-30 22:21:53')
```

Here is the spec that I'm using that generates the above error.

```
# spec/models/contact.rb
require 'spec_helper'
require 'pp'

describe Partners::Contact do

    it "has a valid factory" do
        partner = FactoryGirl.create(:partner_contact)
#       partner.should be_valid
        puts "MEOW MEOW"
    end

    it "is invalid without a firstname" do
#       FactoryGirl.build(:partner_contact, first_name: nil).should_not be_valid
    end

    it "is invalid without a lastname" do
#       FactoryGirl.build(:partner_contact, last_name: nil).should_not be_valid
    end

    it "is invalid without an email address" do
#       FactoryGirl.build(:partner_contact, email: nil).should_not be_valid
    end

    #it "returns a contact's fullname as a string"


end
```

As you can see, it's not trying to commit any data that I listed, first_name, last_name or email. Just 'created_on' which is generated via rails.

What's going on here?

Comment: can you include your specs where you have used this factory

Comment: I'm experiencing a similar issue upgrading from active record 3.2 to 4.1. But it only errors out if the model inherits from ActiveRecord::Base. Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any fixtures for that table? If fixtures are present and enabled, Rails will attempt to load them into your database before your test is evaluated. Look in `spec/fixtures`.

Answer (score 0):

Your setup seems wrong. Check the FactoryGirl Rails [gem](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl_rails). Don't forget to configure RSpec to use FactoryGirl as well.